# Prove this recurrence relation? (catalan numbers)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

$$C_0 = 1,\quad C_{n+1} = C_0C_n + C_1C_{n−1}+ \cdots + C_kC_{n−k} + \cdots + C_nC_0\text{ ?}$$

Where $C_n$ denotes the number of ways of writing a valid list of open and
closed parentheses of length $2n$?

Comment: Check Catalan numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921891/proof-of-recursive-formula-for-catalan-numbers-and-their-interpretation-as-the/921955#921955

Answer (score 3):

$$(1+x)^m(x+1)^m=(1+x)^{2m}$$

The coefficients of  $x^m$   $$\sum_{r=0}\binom mr\binom m{m-r}=\binom{2m}m$$

Comment: Here used the binomial proof. But in the question he asked about Catalan number Cn, but it is not the binomial coefficient