# Path-counting on an 8x8 grid

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider An $8\times8$ grid, and consider the principle diagonal: line-"L", from the lower left vertex, to the upper right vertex. We start at the lower left vertex, and we can move either one unit up, or, one unit to the right.We cannot back-track. We need to find the number of ways to reach the upper right vertex, **without crossing line L**.

My approach:

Lets denote a right move by $R$ , and an up move by $U$. Every single path that leads us from the lower left , to the upper right vertex, is essentially a combination of two types of *sequences*: A right sequence, which consists of consecutive(although variable) $R's$, and an likewise an Up sequence. The number of  right sequences and up sequences are equal. We **must** start with a right sequence, And end with an up sequence. For example, consider a permissible solution: RRRURRUURURURUUU. We have 5 $R$ sequences: {RRR} {RR} {R} {R} {R} and 5 U sequences:{U} {UU} {U} {U} {UUU}.

1. Let there be $k$ right and $k$ up sequences. Let $a_i$ denote the number of $R's$ in the $i'th$ R sequence. Likewise, Let $b_i$ denote the number of $U's$ in the $i'th$ U sequence. Since The total no. of R's = Total no. of U's=8, Thus,$a_1+a_2...a_k=8$ and likewise for $b$.
2. The constraint that ensures that we never cross the diagonal is $(a_i\geq b_i)$ for $1\leq i \leq (k-1)$. The only way i could think of incorporating this, was to consider $a_1+a_2...a_{k-1}=X$
   and $b_1+b_2...b_{k-1}=Y$. Subtracting, and letting $A_i$ =$(a_i- b_i)$, we get $A_1+A_2....=(X-Y)$. X-Y ranges from 0 to 7, and since all A's are positive,(from the constraint), We can easily find the number of solutions for A in terms of $k$.$k$ varies from $1$ to $8$.

   3.But this hardly helps, as if we now try to count the no. of solution of a and b,From A, we get a giant mess.

I think my approach has simply described the problem in terms of a few variables: computing the no. solutions *easily* from my analysis doesnt seem to be likely. Any other insight to my approach/alternative approach would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921891/proof-of-recursive-formula-for-catalan-numbers-and-their-interpretation-as-the

Comment: You can find a closed form expression for the Catalan number by searching this site.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics

Comment: Is there any way to end up with $C_n$ using my approach?